# Backbone.js- I got this error message ReferenceError {}

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, underscore.js

hello i am newbie in require.js and backbone.js i need u help for my development programming..

i have code in :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scaleable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/red.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" />
  <script>
    curl = {
      apiName: 'require'
    };
  </script>
  <script src="js/libs/amd/require.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div data-add-back-btn="true" data-role="page" id="accountenquiry" data-url="/accountenquiry"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

views/account-enquiry/AccountEnquiryView.js

```
define([
       'underscore',
       'backbone',
       'text!templates/account-enquiry/accountenquiry.html'
], function(_, Backbone, tmpl){

    var serverUrl = 'http://localhost/agro-rib-mobile/restful/crud/get_all_accounts.php';

    Account = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: serverUrl,
    parse: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      return response;
    },
    defaults: {
        ACCOUNT_ID: null,
        ACCOUNT_TYPE: '',
        FULL_NAME: '',
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER : '',
        CURRENT_BALANCE: 0
    }


});

    var AccountCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Account,
    urlRoot: serverUrl,
    parse: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      return response;
    }
});


  var AccountEnquiryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#accountenquiry',
    template: _.template(tmpl),

    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Initializing Account Enquiry');

    },

    render: function() {

        var AccountsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Account,
        url: serverUrl,
        parse: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          return response;
        }
      });

        var accounts = new AccountsCollection;
        accounts.fetch();

        //console.log(accounts.toJSON());

      $(this.el).html(this.template(accounts.toJSON()));
      return this;
    }

  });

  return AccountEnquiryView;

});
```

templates/account-enquiry/accountenquiry.html

```
<!-- Start of second page: two -->
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Account Enquiry</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    <p>All Account</p>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="ui-responsive" id="my-table" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="50%">Account</th>

                <th width="50%">Current Balance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <% _.each(accounts, function(account) { %>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <span><strong>Current Account(s)</strong></span><br>
                    <a class="detail" href="#/accountdisplay">
                     <%= account.FULL_NAME %>   </a><br>
                    <span>19710257104</span>
                </td>

                <td>RM1,411,421,532</td>
            </tr>
            <% }); %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Why i got this error? ReferenceError {}

Comment: Your browser's console tells you all you need

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console as you can see every error has stack trace and you can define what causes an issue.

Comment: Or please provide a jsfiddle because it is not so easy to parse all your code and define what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already fix it :)

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/account-enquiry/accountenquiry.html'], function(_, Backbone, tmpl) {
    var serverUrl = 'http://localhost/agro-rib-mobile/restful/crud/get_all_accounts.php';
    AccountModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var AccountCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: AccountModel,
        urlRoot: serverUrl,
        parse: function(response) {
            return response;
        }
    });
    var AccountEnquiryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#accountenquiry',
        initialize: function() {
        },
        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            this.collection = new AccountCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({
                  success: function(collection, response) {
                   var template = _.template(tmpl, {
                     accounts: that.collection.models
                   });
                   that.$el.html(template);
                  },
                  error: function(collection, response) {
                    alert("error");
                  }
            });

        }
    });
    return AccountEnquiryView;
});
```